# how do I scrape form the website which has next button and also if it scrolling?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape all the data from a website called quotestoscrape. But, When I try to run my code it's only getting the one random quote. It should take at least all the data from that page only but it's only taking one. Also, if somehow I get the data from page 1 now what I want is to get the data from all the pages.

1. So how do I solve this error(which should take all the data from the page1)?
2. How do I take all the data which is present on the next pages?

items.py file

```
    import scrapy
    class QuotetutorialItem(scrapy.Item):

        title = scrapy.Field()
        author = scrapy.Field()
        tag = scrapy.Field()
```

quotes_spider.py file

```
import scrapy
from ..items import QuotetutorialItem

class QuoteScrapy(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        items = QuotetutorialItem()

        all_div_quotes = response.css('div.quote')

        for quotes in all_div_quotes:
            title = quotes.css('span.text::text').extract()
            author = quotes.css('.author::text').extract()
            tag = quotes.css('.tag::text').extract()

            items['title'] = title
            items['author'] = author
            items['tag'] = tag

        yield items
```

Please tell me what change I can do?

Comment: `yield` should be indented I believe

Comment: oh, it worked thanks. Now can you look at my second problem?

Comment: second page can be found at http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/

Comment: About yield statement why is it that it doesn't give me an indentation error. Why is it only returning one item?

Comment: Because it's perfectly valid to have a `yield` statement there, it just doesn't mean what you want it to mean. Indenting it an extra time puts it inside the `for` loop. Leaving it where you showed it puts it outside the `for` loop, but still inside the `parse` function. In this case you only get one item because the `yield` is only reached once - after the loop has finished running.

Answer (score 1):

As reported, it's missing an ident level on your yield. And to follow next pages, just add a check for the next button, and yield a request following it.

```
import scrapy


class QuoteScrapy(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        items = {}

        all_div_quotes = response.css('div.quote')

        for quotes in all_div_quotes:
            title = quotes.css('span.text::text').extract()
            author = quotes.css('.author::text').extract()
            tag = quotes.css('.tag::text').extract()

            items['title'] = title
            items['author'] = author
            items['tag'] = tag

            yield items

        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page)
```

Comment: Do I have to go to the next page and run it again in order to save the next page data?

Comment: No.  The last 3 lines will extract the link from the Next button and make a new request to the next page. This request will be parsed by the same parse method, yielding all items present on all pages.

`next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()`


So we check if there is a next page with:

if next_page

Then we yield a new request with the line bellow. Note that response.follow is a shortcut for `urllib.urljoin(response.url, next_url)`, because it's a relative URL.

yield response.follow(next_page)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Also, I want to know if it doesn't have the next page button and instead if I have to scroll through pages will it work the same? or is there another logic to that?

Comment: In case of infinite scrolling, the best option would be investigate the API it uses to request data when scrolling down. You can do it opening the Dev Console(Ctrl + Shift + C) on google chrome, going to 'Network' tab, filter by XHR requests and look for the request that fetch data when you scroll down the page.

Once you got the API request, you can use it on your spider to fetch data the same way the page does when you scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

As @LanteDellaRovere has correctly identified in a comment, the `yield` statement should be executed for each iteration of the `for` loop - which is why you are only seeing a single (presumably the last) link from each page.

As far as reading the continued pages, you could extract it from the `<nav>` element at the bottom of the page, but the structure is very simple - the links (when no tag is specified) are of the form

```
http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/N/
```

You will find that for N=1 you get the first page. So just access the URLs for increasing values of N until the attempt sees a 404 return should work as a simplistic solution.

Not knowing much about Scrapy I can't give you exact code, but the examples at https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#following-links are fairly helpful if you want a more sophisticated and Pythonic approach.

Comment: Hi, Suppose I have 50 number of pages and I have to extract them all. I don't think it will be helpful in that situation. Sure it will work in this because it has limited pages. Is there any solution can you tell?

Comment: I'd go with the answer from @Marcos if I were you - it appears to be based on sound knowledge of how to use Scrapy.